# Fint A\C using algorithms

Tags: calculus

I have problems understanding a chapter called "Decidability". If I have A=semi-decidable and C=decidable, why A\C will be semi-decidable? I don't understand why. Is there any demonstration for that? I made only recursion at school and what I understand is that if A=semi-decidable this means that it will be recursively and if C=decidable means that is recursively enumerable, meaning that A\C will be also recursively enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

It is the other way. *Semi-decidable* can be identified with recursively enumerable, and *decidable* with recursive.

Here is an informal argument for showing that if $A$ is semi-decidable, and $C$ is decidable, then $A\setminus C$ is semi-decidable.

Because $A$ is semi-decidable, there is an algorithm $T_A$ that will accept a word $w$ if and only if $w\in A$. If $w\not\in A$, the algorithm may terminate and say "not in," but it could run forever without halting.

Because $C$ is decidable, there is an algorithm which will halt and say yes if $w\in C$, and will halt and say no if $w\not\in C$.

Now we construct an algorithm $T$ that accepts $w$ if and only if $w\in A\setminus C$, and either rejects or runs forever if $w\not\in A\setminus C$.

First run $T_C$ on $W$. If $T_C$ accepts $w$, meaning that $w\in C$, then $T$ rejects $w$. If $T_C$ rejects $w$, start running $T_A$ on $w$. It is not difficult to see that $T$ accepts $w$ if and only if $w\in A\setminus C$.